# Update content of multiple pages/posts at once?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, bulk-import, scheduled-posts

Is this possible? using shortcodes? Custom post type? Custom Fields? CSV upload?

Unique content per page.
Do not need to create new pages, Just update body of them.

Seems like a tough one?

Also can this be scheduled.

---

Specifically there are a dozen Horoscope pages, with a paragraph of text. I'd like to update each Horoscope paragraph (replace) with new text daily but leave page intact. Also would be great to schedule these updates.

Comment: How do you mean, update content? Update it how? Append to it? replace it? and with what exactly?

Comment: +1 on the above. Also, could you describe a scenario where you need to do this sort of thing? I'm curious about the use case.

Comment: In my case, there are about a dozen pages, with a paragraph of text. I'd like to update each paragraph with new text daily, but leave page intact. Also would be great to schedule these updates.

Comment: where does the content come from?

Comment: Thats the next question, could I upload a a file? xml?

Comment: Why have a page for a single paragraph? Could you not consolidate all that information into a single page, give that page a template, then add a query var onto requests to that page to determine which starsign to show(could default to the first sign when one isn't present). You could add one or two rewrite rules to pretty up the URLs to. Sorry i don't have time to write some proof of concept code(but that would be my approach).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways I might approach this.

The least intrusive would be to add a few empty spans or divs on your page and use the [jQuery `get` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to fill these with text from the appropriate file.

Another possibility, but less secure would be to use a [plugin that allows you to execute php code in your page](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/). There are some serious security risks to this if you've got a group edited blog.

The most secure would be to define your own shortcode to do this, either as a custom plugin or in your theme's `functions.php`.

All of these would allow you to bulk upload multiple days worth of files, and automatically load the correct one by day. The jQuery option would be the easiest to load the correct horoscope for the current visitor.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I need a crash course in jQuery, could anyone point me in the right direction to accomplish the task above?

Comment: The last example on the [get documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) should get you started, as well as the [append documentation](http://api.jquery.com/append/)